# Regular Expression, what is wrong with this RegEx?

Tags: regex

first off, I am sorry for this awful questiontitle but I couldnt figure out a better one.

So I am trying to build a little tool with Python to enhance my skills, it scrapes data off Imdb.com and outputs titles and other stuff filtered from the HTML.

I am using this RegEx for my Search: `<h3 class="findSectionHeader"><a name="tt"><\/a>Titles<\/h3>[\s]{0,3}(.*?)<\/td> <\/tr><\/table>` which should result everything after `a>Titles<\/h3>` and before `<\/tr><\/table>` but I am doing something wrong. I have added the [\s]{0,3} because I thought it could be because of \n or something else but it didnt fix it at all.

this is the source block:

```
<div class="findSection">
<h3 class="findSectionHeader"><a name="tt"></a>Titles</h3>
<table class="findList">
<tr class="findResult odd"> <td class="primary"> <a href="/title/tt1474684/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1" >
<img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/_AL_.jpg" />
</a> </td> <td class="result_text"> 
<a href="/title/tt1474684<a href="/title/tt3155298/?ref_=fn_al_tt_3" >
<img src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/imagestd class="primary_photo"> 
<a href="/tiopicture/32x44/film-3119741174._CB522736599_.png" /></a>
</td> <td class="result_text"> 
<a href="/title/tt1501661/?ref_=fn_al_tt_10" >Luther</a> (1968) (TV Movie) </td> </tr></table>
```

Comment: Don't try to tackle HTML with regex, use a DOM parser instead. [Beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) should be a good starting point for python.

Comment: The problem is that your `.*?` doesn't match line breaks. It works as expected if you enable single-line mode `s`.

Comment: @rawing Ah thanks, it also works when using `([\s\S]*?)` to match any character, whitespace aswell as non-whitespace character! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following *regex* :

```
(?s)(?<=<\/h3>\n).*?(?=</tr></table>)
```

*see **[regex demo / explanation](https://regex101.com/r/yer2N2/1)***

**python**

```
import re
regex = r"(?s)(?<=<\/h3>\n).*?(?=</tr></table>)"
str = """<div class="findSection">
<h3 class="findSectionHeader"><a name="tt"></a>Titles</h3>
<table class="findList">
<tr class="findResult odd"> <td class="primary"> <a href="/title/tt1474684/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1" >
<img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/_AL_.jpg" />
</a> </td> <td class="result_text"> 
<a href="/title/tt1474684<a href="/title/tt3155298/?ref_=fn_al_tt_3" >
<img src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/imagestd class="primary_photo"> 
<a href="/tiopicture/32x44/film-3119741174._CB522736599_.png" /></a>
</td> <td class="result_text"> 
<a href="/title/tt1501661/?ref_=fn_al_tt_10" >Luther</a> (1968) (TV Movie) </td> </tr></table>"""
matches = re.finditer(regex, str)
for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
    matchNum = matchNum + 1
    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the flag `re.DOTALL` to your `re` call so that `.` matches newline characters:

```
src = '''<div class="findSection">
<h3 class="findSectionHeader"><a name="tt"></a>Titles</h3>
<table class="findList">
<tr class="findResult odd"> <td class="primary"> <a href="/title/tt1474684/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1" >
<img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/_AL_.jpg" />
</a> </td> <td class="result_text"> 
<a href="/title/tt1474684<a href="/title/tt3155298/?ref_=fn_al_tt_3" >
<img src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/imagestd class="primary_photo"> 
<a href="/tiopicture/32x44/film-3119741174._CB522736599_.png" /></a>
</td> <td class="result_text"> 
<a href="/title/tt1501661/?ref_=fn_al_tt_10" >Luther</a> (1968) (TV Movie) </td> </tr></table>'''

expr = r'<h3 class="findSectionHeader"><a name="tt"><\/a>Titles<\/h3>[\s]{0,3}(.*?)<\/td> <\/tr><\/table>'

import re

print re.findall( expr, src, re.DOTALL )
```

yields:

```
['<table class="findList">\n<tr class="findResult odd"> <td class="primary"> <a href="/title/tt1474684/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1" >\n<img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/_AL_.jpg" />\n</a> </td> <td class="result_text"> \n<a href="/title/tt1474684<a href="/title/tt3155298/?ref_=fn_al_tt_3" >\n<img src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/imagestd class="primary_photo"> \n<a href="/tiopicture/32x44/film-3119741174._CB522736599_.png" /></a>\n</td> <td class="result_text"> \n<a href="/title/tt1501661/?ref_=fn_al_tt_10" >Luther</a> (1968) (TV Movie) ']
```

Comment: Actually this was what I have tried yesterday like this: `result = re.findall(r'REGEX', str(result), flags=re.DOTALL)` but it didnt work, maybe I failed.